# Can Ansible (control node) report what version of Python it's using?

Tags: python-3.x, ansible

I'm setting up Ansible on a control node with a number of Python interpreters. Ansible has [some rules to discover a Python interpreter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html).

Is there a way to have the ansible command to echo back what python version (or location of the interpreter) it's using?

Comment: Do you need more than what `ansible --version` is reporting ?

Comment: That works perfectly! @Zeitounator Turn that into an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment above to an answer.

`ansible --version` will report several info about the control machine among which the python version and the path to the ansible library being used

Example:

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.8.0
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/home/user1/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) [GCC 8.2.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [setup_module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/setup_module.html) like this:

```
ansible -m setup REMOTEHOST | grep “ansible_python_version”
```

Comment: This will report the python version used when connnecting to localhost to manage it, which can be different from the python version used by ansible itself.